# How to set a flag in docker at the time of start

Tags: docker, centos, storage

My docker was running fine but don't know why near about before 32 hours docker daemon stopped .

So i tried to run the daemon again `sudo systemctl start docker` . Everything was fine . But when i tried to restart the containers using `docker restart $(docker ps -aq)`.

I am getting error in mounting `overlay2` . I investigate on google and came to know that overlay2 driver is not supported by my server that's why I am facing this issue.

SO now i have to update the storage driver for docker using flag `--storage-driver` so i tried `sudo systemctl start docker --storage-driver devicemapper` but geting error  `systemctl: unrecognized option '--storage-driver'`

Does anyone know how to do it ?

docker version : `Docker version 1.13.1, build 6e3bb8e/1.13.1`
os :

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Thanks.

Comment: which docker version and os version you are using ?

Comment: Note 1.13.1 is very old and unsupported. 18.09 is the latest stable release, 18.06.x is the release I currently recommend (waiting on 18.09.1 for some fixes).

Comment: So if I will update the docker . So can I get my old data back in volumes? @BMitch

Comment: Data in volumes will still be there. If you change the storage driver, you will lose images and containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the storage driver with a /etc/docker/daemon.json file that contains the following:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper"
}
```

I've had much better luck with overlay2, so if you can upgrade your kernel to support the new driver, I'd recommend that instead.

Comment: echo '{ "storage-driver": "devicemapper" }' | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json tried this

Comment: sudo systemctl restart docker run this

Comment: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: storage-driver: (from flag: overlay2, from file: devicemapper) getting this error

Comment: You need to find the flags and remove them. /etc/defaults/docker and /etc/systemd/system/docker* are two common locations.

Comment: Let me check this